# Kendo Angular 2 Slider (Beta version) - no labels

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have used the Kendo UI slider for Angular JS and it produces a nice interface that looks something like this (see image A):

[image: Kendo Slider for Angular JS]

I am have been trying to get the beta version working with Angular2. It seems to be pretty simple and straightforward but I cannot seem to get the numbers to show above the tick marks (when the slider is changed) and below the tick marks (they are always present to indicate scale). Please see the [Overview](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/slider/) page or the [API](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/SliderComponent/) doc to point out what I am doing wrong. This seems so simple but I'm just not seeing it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about the labels option, am I correct? If this is the case - then the current version of the Slider does not have it implemented. Definitely part of the plans for future releases.

Comment: Yes, Thank You for the answer.